# Invoking std::thread with class operator()() that has CWinThread as base fails

Tags: c++, mfc, stdthread

**Background:**

My project is `C++ MFC`. But I am writing the code using modern C++ as the standard evolves. Currently, I invoke threads sometimes using `std::thread` (later code) and sometimes the MFC `CreateThread` complete with required `waitForSingleObject` and thread priority parameter. Clearly, the `std::thread` is more elegant and therefore more maintainable. It is important to over time make the code consistent and drop old idioms where possible.

**Problem:**

But invoking `std::thread` with a class `Baz` in sample code below that has `CWinThread` as its base, fails to find a `std::thread` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

**Sample Code:**

```
struct Caz {};
struct Baz : public CWinThread // works if base is Caz
{
  void operator()() {}
};

std::shared_ptr< Baz > b;
b = std::make_shared< Baz >();

std::thread bazThread( *b ); // error: can't find a constructor when CWinThread is base, but can for Caz as base
```

When the base class is `CWinThread` it fails to resolve, but when the base class is `Caz` it works fine. Both `Caz` and `CWinThread` have default constructors.

Why is `CWinThread` making it fail?

**Edit1:**

The error message set is:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2057,35): error C2665: 'std::tuple::tuple': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\tuple(321,5): message : could be 'std::tuple::tuple(std::tuple &&)'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\tuple(320,5): message : or       'std::tuple::tuple(const std::tuple &)'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2056,59): message : while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty2)'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2056,59): message :         with
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2056,59): message :         [
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2056,59): message :             _Ty2=Baz
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\memory(2056,59): message :         ]
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<_Tuple,std::default_delete<_Ty>> std::make_unique<_Tuple,_Ty2&,0>(_Ty2 &)' being compiled
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message :         with
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message :         [
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message :             _Ty=_Tuple,
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message :             _Ty2=Baz
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message :         ]
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<_Ty2&,,void>(_Fn)' being compiled
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message :         with
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message :         [
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message :             _Ty2=Baz,
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message :             _Fn=Baz &
>
> 1>E:\Hiveware\trunk\Windows\hives\Hiveware\SdcdcHiveware\GrammarSdcdcHiveware.cpp(153): message :         ]
>
> 1>Done building project "SdcdcHiveware.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

**Edit2:**

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE make_unique
template <class _Ty, class... _Types, enable_if_t<!is_array_v<_Ty>, int> = 0>
_NODISCARD unique_ptr<_Ty> make_unique(_Types&&... _Args) { // make a unique_ptr
    return unique_ptr<_Ty>(new _Ty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...));
}
```

Comment: The construcor of `Baz` is irrelevant since the `b` object is already constructed and `std::thread` will simply call its `operator()`. What is the EXACT and COMPLETE error message?

Comment: IIRC `CWinThread` is not copyable which is what `std::thread bazThread( *b );` tries to do.

Comment: In **Edit2:** is the function the compiler fails to compile with `CWinThread` as base.

Answer (score 0):

Tentative answer unless someone finds a workaround.

`std::thread` cannot be used in `MFC` projects for class types that inherit from `CWinThread`, also called `user threads` for which sample code may be found at [Creating Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads).

For traditional windows `worker threads` invoking std::thread instead works fine.